Grainy texture overlay (not a physical screen protector) on the monitor screen
I have a Xiaomi Android device and there I have a setting to add a grainy screen texture and control the intensity of it. I like this feature as it gives a paperlike experience and is eye-comforting. So I wonder if there is any way to achieve the same effect on my desktop screen.

Please [edit] your question and add more detail. First of all, mention your operating system (don't use a tag for it, tell us in the question). If Arch, then also tell us if you are using a graphical environment and, if so, which one. A screenshot of the effect you are looking for could also help.
